# Cannot find module 'npmlog'

Tags: npm, npm-install

Hello I receive the following message when trying to install npm. I downloaded the most recent node.js but it doesn't seem to download npm. I keep getting the below`enter code here` error message after deleting node.js and reinstalling it.

When I try installing node.js I don't see the following being created:

```
    C:\Users\Efren Barragan\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

This is the first time installing node.js. I just installed it on my old computer and it worked out fine. I am new to this so so your patience is much appreciated! Thanks!

```
C:\Users\Efren Barragan> npm install npm -g
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at C:\Users\Efren Barragan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:19:13
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Efren Barragan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:75:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Comment: I'm suffering exactly the same problem here - except the line number which on my console is 442 . What version npm did you install? I'm using 6.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a newer version, it's been a bug in previous version.

Comment: Hello, I just found the solution. I deleted all npm files through File Explorer and installed node.js again. I don't know why but it worked now..thanks!

Comment: I installed both the LTS latest and Current latest from [nodejs.org/en/download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) - 4.4.6 and 6.2.2 - with exactly the same problem. Win7. Tried de-installing and re-installing multiple times.

Comment: My issue resolved itself overnight after 4 days of hell.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the bug in versions this is what i did -

I have faced the same issue in my Windows 10 PC. After looking into solutions, since i couldn't find the exact solution for the issue i was facing
**Cannot find module 'npmlog'**
I just uninstalled the node js and then, deleted both 'npm' and 'npm-cache' in 
"C:\Users\YourPCName\AppData\Roaming"

Then, i downloaded the latest version of node from [Node JS Website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

And, installed node js

After that i checked with the path in environment variables.

Finally run the command prompt 'run as administrator' and **npm install npm -g**

Checking your version will show the latest version. 'npm -v'

I got the latest version - v3.10.9

Try this. this should work.